# Intercept RequestSecurityTokenResponse with SOAPHandler

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I'm using apache CXF to process soap messages. I need to handle RequestSecurityTokenResponse to take an Identifier associated with MessageID from RequestSecurityToken (request). I've added SOAPHandler as follows:

```
<camel-cxf:cxfEndpoint id="serviceEndpoint"
                address="..."
                serviceClass="..."
                wsdlURL="..."
                endpointName="..."
                serviceName="..."
                xmlns:s="...">
    <camel-cxf:properties>
        <entry key="ws-security.callback-handler" value-ref="keystorePasswordCallbackHandler" />
        <entry key="security.sts.token.do.cancel" value="true" />
    </camel-cxf:properties>
    <camel-cxf:handlers>
        <bean class="ws.MySoapHandler" />
    </camel-cxf:handlers>
</camel-cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

where MySoapHandler logs inbound/outbound messages:

```
public class MySoapHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingHandler.class);

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return new HashSet<>();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        Boolean isOutBound = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        try {
            if (isOutBound){
                log.info("############# Intercepting outbound message #############");
            } else {
                log.info("############# Intercepting inbound message #############");
            }
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            context.getMessage().writeTo(baos);
            log.info(baos.toString());
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) {
        System.out.println("Do some cleanup handling .. ");
    }
}
```

When I check logs, I don't see  RequestSecurityTokenResponse message.
Can you tell me why? Is it possible to handle RequestSecurityTokenResponse